# XTS in R studio

Tags: r, xts

I'm reading a binary output file of a program using a R package. When I executed the below line of code I see a data structure as shown in the snapshot under the 'Environment' tab of R Studio.

```
output <- read_out("test.out", iType = 0, object_name = "RG1", vIndex = c(0,3))
```

My question is how do get the information of 'both 'rainfall_rate' and 'infiltration_loss' into a single XTS table rather than as seen in the snapshot?
I tried running the code below. However, I'd want to bring both 'rainfall_rate' and 'infiltration_loss' under the table 'x'.

```
x <- read_output[["RG1"]][["rainfall_rate"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question about R Studio, it is a question about R. We will assume that what you have is `read_output` below.

Now, xts objects require a date or date/time index and without that we cannot produce an xts object but we can produce a zoo (z) or ts (tt) series with index 1, 2, 3, ... as shown.

```
library(xts)
read_output <- list(RG1 = list(rainfall_rate = 1:5, infiltration_rate = 11:15))

z <- zoo(as.data.frame(read_output$RG1))
tt <- as.ts(as.data.frame(read_output$RG1))
```

If this were daily data starting January 1, 1800 then we could write:

```
zr <- zooreg(as.data.frame(read_output$RG1), start = as.Date("1800-01-01"))
x <- as.xts(zr)
x
##            rainfall_rate infiltration_rate
## 1800-01-01             1                11
## 1800-01-02             2                12
## 1800-01-03             3                13
## 1800-01-04             4                14
## 1800-01-05             5                15
```

or if it were an hourly series starting January 1, 2014 then we could write this where 3600 means that the points are 3600 seconds (1 hour) apart.

```
st <- as.POSIXct("2014-01-01")
zz <- zooreg(as.data.frame(read_output$RG1), start = st, deltat = 3600)
xx <- as.xts(zz)
xx
##                     rainfall_rate infiltration_rate
## 2014-01-01 00:00:00             1                11
## 2014-01-01 01:00:00             2                12
## 2014-01-01 02:00:00             3                13
## 2014-01-01 03:00:00             4                14
## 2014-01-01 04:00:00             5                15
```